# Как запустить несколько скайпов на Win 10 (новая версия скайпа)

Tags: windows, windows-10, skype

Как запустить несколько скайпов на Win 10 (новая версия скайпа)?
В Интернете только один способ (добавить в путь ярлыка /secondory), но как только обновился скайп, этот способ перестал работать. Очень нужно для работы иметь несколько рабочих скайпов. Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить параллельно копию скайпа?

Comment: А вам не подойдет Скайп (встроенный в Windows 10) и skype скачанный с сайта для Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Песочница [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/), Виртуальная машина [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/ru.html), Можно запускать программы с параметром, указывающим какой аккаунт/профиль использовать. Вот инструкция: [Гайд](http://www.wseven.info/runas/)

Comment: А попроще? Раньше можно было просто изменить путь в ярлыке и сразу запускалась копия.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Не надо таких извращений. Вот инструкция https://mskc.pro/novyj-skype-dlya-windows/#4  у меня 3 новвх Скайпа работают одновременно

Answer (score 0):

Найти файл-приложение в папке (в нее можно перейти, если в диспетчере процессов развернуть skype и на любой ветки нажать правой кнопкой -> открыть место расположения) следующего вида:
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.66.77.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c\Skype\Skype.exe"

Создать ярлык для Skype.exe на рабочем столе. И в параметрах запуска (параметр "Объект") в конец добавить " --secondary" (без кавычек). С этого ярлыка можно запускать второй экземпляр. Также можно этот ярлык использовать при автозапуске.